# C++ to C conversion workflow

Tags: c++, c

First thing, I am not looking for a tool that is going to produce an unmaintainable C code from an existing cpp code-base. It is a requirement from a client, so I cannot just use the CPP code base itself.

I am trying to work out a work-flow, so that I can convert the code-base from CPP to C incrementally without breaking the code. I have thought out a few things using the "extern C" approach

1. Classes to Structs
2. Member functions of the Classes will be converted to Struct_name_FunctionName format.
3. In case of a function being re-used by 2 classes, I plan to use function pointers.
4. Replace overloaded operators like +,- etc with actual functions. Eg a Add_, Sub_ etc

Can you folks add anymore ?
and point out potential pit-falls ? 
I cannot share the code-base because of NDA.
The code base isn't huge in itself. Its got around 50 cpp files, saw some 100 odd classes.

Thanks in advance.

P.s I have gone through some other questions that sound similar. But they don't really have the work-flow that I am looking for.

[Closing] : Although the post has been put on hold because it is too broad, many of the comments were in fact useful. I am clearer on what needs to be done than before. Thank you.

Comment: I already did something similar. To have a good result each class must be a new .c file with classname.c Each private method has to be static. Each public method has to be externalized into classname.h file. All the thing you wrote are a good way to do that.

Comment: Don't think of *converting* the code to C, but of *rewriting* new code in C. C++ and C are *different* languages.

Comment: What about overloads?

Comment: Overloads wil be differet functions, with different names. No other ways.

Comment: FWIW, some templates can be approximated using macros that spew out type-specific "instantiations"....

Comment: And as someone mentioned before, creating a test harness can be really useful. You can first create a test harness for the C++ code, with CppUnit or similar software. Then, you write a wrapper which implements the exact same C++ API you started out with, but is implemented in terms of your C code. This way you can keep the exact same tests in C++, to test both versions of the code base.

Comment: Is there actually a good technical reason for wanting to do this or is it just an arbitrary requirement from your client?

Comment: Are you **really** sure your client wants the **whole** codebase converted? Not just having a "pure C" **interface**? The latter is a common request, the former is... I hesitate to call it nonsense, but I really don't see the return-on-investment on this. Anyway, this question is much too broad to be answered in this format.

Comment: 4 close votes? Really? Seems like a good question to me.

Comment: I hope you don't have multiple (virtual) inheritance in your C++ code, because that *would* get ghastly.

Comment: What is the size of this project?

Comment: Here is [a project](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) that help you to code OO in C.

Comment: @abligh: While a good question *per se*, it's something you could write a sizeable book about. "Good answers would be too long for this format", it says right there in the reasoning.

Comment: @DevSolar This is a embedded system application and the client requires a C implementation of the same. Probably because C is preferred when dealing with porting the application to a wide range of plantforms.

Comment: @vikasmk: That's a 1999 approach to embedded systems. The most common compiler for embedded systems today is GCC, and it will support most of C++11 and good chunks of C++14.

Comment: @MSalters That may be so. But it is a requirement. So, nothing can be done about it.

Answer (score 9):

Well, there's a very long list you'll have to tackle. Without claiming to be complete, you also need:

1. Virtual function support (not impossibly hard, function pointer table)
2. Constructors and destructors (Reasonable mapping to ordinary functions, lot of work)
3. Exceptions and stack unwinding (extremely hard)
4. Missing C++ library functions and classes (lot of work)

But don't kid yourself. `std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, int>>` is a very straightforward class that stores two ints for each string. The C translation of that class is an outright mess. `MyMap["five,three"] = std::make_pair(5,3)` can easily become 100+ lines of C code.

Comment: Just to add another thing, templates are the first thing that came to my mind - if you have a templated function that uses an overloaded operator on the template type, just saying "Add_whatever" isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @Random832: That's not actually such a big deal. When translating C++ to C, you will have to manually instantiate each template anyway. You can/must look up all the correct "overloads" yourself in the process.

Answer (score 4):

If your C++ code makes extensive use of OO constructs - particularly inheritance and polymorphism - you might wish to look at some C libraries that mimic this in C. qobject (from the qemu source tree) is one I know well, but better known (to nearly everyone bar me) is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject which comes from glib. Nowadays, that isn't tied up with GUI code.

The advantage here is that you can change the language in use without making too many changes to the program flow.

glib also provides a fair number of other useful library constructs.

Answer (score 2):

Following the advice to take the GObject as an example how C++-like code is done in C, there's one thing you can try out:

1. Translate the C++ code to Vala
2. Generate C code from Vala compiler.

Vala is a C#-like language; except that you'll have to repeat "public" or "private" in every function signature, as well as get rid of pointer-star in class types in use, there's no much things you'll have to do.

Of course, the generated C code will look the same ugly as from the other generators, but at least there are some short ways how to make it a "maintainable" code (the main problem is that every object created in Vala results in incrementing reference counter in C code, which isn't always necessary).

The GObject model can be a nice instruction/example as to how to translate C++ constructs into the same in C. If you don't use exceptions (Vala does! :) ), there should be no trouble with that. Of course the main guidelines are:

1. Normal methods: use the pointer to object as first argument. The function name is NAMESPACE_CLASSNAME_METHODNAME.
2. Virtual methods: you have to create a "characteristic object", pointed by the "object" of that class, which contains pointers to functions. The class's characteristic objects are usually created in GObject in functions that return pointer to that object - the object itself is lazily created and saved in a static local variable.
3. Overloading: add name-distinguising parts (Vala does not support overloading, even in constructors - constructors use special syntax for calling named constructors)
4. Templates: expand in place :)
5. Derivation: single derivation only (as in Vala as well), make the first field of the "derived class" structure the field of type of the "base class" structure.
6. Calling methods from base classes: use C cast. If you follow the point 5, you should simply cast the structure of derived class object to the structure of the base class.

Comment: To your point 6: If you use a convention to call the base-class suboboject `super` in all cases, you can just write `&me->super` instead of `(*BaseClass)me`. While both expressions compile to the same assembler code (which is to say none), the first one allows the compiler to check whether the type conversion is appropriate. You only need casts for downcasting as in C++.

Comment: Not if you have second-derived class, in which case you have `&me->super->super` or third derived etc. - while the cast to base always have the same syntax. And the fact that you have a type check is insignificant in C (you wouldn't have an error, but only a warning), especially that in C you must cast if you do advanced stuff. The "downcasting" is actually a rare case in C++. The GObject does really a pretty good job to provide a good enough OO programming model, but also proves that chosing C for that task is rarely a good idea (unless you have no choice).

Comment: I only know a little about Vala, but won't this leave you with code written in Vala, rather than code written in C?

Comment: @abligh Vala is a language that's compiled to C, not to assembler. As such, it is possible to rewrite the code in Vala, compile it, and dump the result to the customer. Maybe he'll like it, maybe not...

Comment: @cmaster his first statement is *"First thing, I am not looking for a tool that is going to produce an unmaintainable C code from an existing cpp code-base."* - how would the C (as opposed to the Vala) be maintainable?

Comment: @abligh Unmaintainability is in the eye of the observer. I've seen a *lot* of code that's totally unmaintainable even though it's written by humans, and that's even worse to read than than result of vala compilation. And you can't deny that the code that comes out of vala compilation is working C code. Still, you are right, the vala solution is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Ethouris Would you ever ignore a warning about an implicit pointer conversion? I won't. Such warnings are almost certainly bugs, and if not, I'll add the required cast to ensure that I actually see future warnings. Unfortunately `gcc` doesn't allow turning this kind of warnings into errors because it's one of those warnings that you can't disable, precisely because it is almost always a bug XD

Comment: @cmaster when I really want to have a compiler that can point me out any potential bug, I'd rather never choose C language for that. What's the deal that C gives me ignorable warning, where C++ gives me error?

Comment: @abligh: Yes, I know, that's why I said that in the beginning. However the C code produced from Vala isn't "*that ugly*". This is only a matter of balance - whether it is cheaper (less time and effort) to rewrite it manually to C or to rewrite it to Vala and then fix the generated C code.